# Are WebSphere 6.1 and WebSphere 8 compatible?

Tags: webserver, websphere

I want to migrate an old EJB 2.1 (with Xdoclet usage) project from Websphere 6.1 to WebSphere 8. 

Is there anything to be taken into account. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to this link:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc%2Finfo%2Fae%2Fae%2Frovr_specs.html

However, support for specifications is compatible with earlier versions of the product; the Version 8.0 product supports all specifications that are listed for Version 6.0 through Version 8.0. For example, for any application type, the Version 8.0 product supports **Java EE 5 and 6 and J2EE 1.2, 1.3, and 1.4**.

You should be able to run EJB 2.1 on WAS 8 based on this information above.

HTH

Manglu

Answer (score 0):

In general the Java EE specification APIs should function the same between WAS versions mentioned (Java EE 1.4 for WAS v6.1, Java 6 EE for WAS v8), but the quickest way to know for certain is to download and install the WebSphere Application Server Migration Toolkit (WAMT), a freely available Eclipse plugin, which will identify changes needed for Java EE APIs, WebSphere APIs and Java SE.

WAMT is available from the Eclipse Marketplace as well as from https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/downloads/migtoolkit/